# How to get Top players using Facebook Graph

Tags: ios, facebook, graph

Im developing new game, in this game each player should connect to Facebook to playand I want to get list of top players (Non friends) playing my game
is there anyway to do it??

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 0):

Shortly: No. Facebook Scores API doesn't provide a direct interface to retrieve **all** users scores unfortunately. One can only display his friends' scores using `/APP_ID/scores` request.

However, another method might be to store the scores of your players in your own structure on your own hosting and keep a global scores list. Nevertheless it would be wise to first check if it complies with the privacy policies of Facebook and Apple to do so.